# Positioning an element next to a Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little arrow element that's part of a Bootstrap Modal and points to the element that triggered the modal to open.

This works fine. However, if the modal is very long and requires the user to scroll then the arrow element no longer remains stationary, pointing to the trigger element. This means I have to place the arrow outside of the `.modal-dialogue` div, which means it hangs to the left side of the page.

Would anyone know how I could position the arrow so it's consistently next to the modal?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umv4jhLg/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="mymodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        CONTENT
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    <div class="modal-arrow"></div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS

```
.modal-content {
  height: 800px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.modal-arrow {
    content: "";
    display: block; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 35px 25px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/L0r14amn/2/) of your fiddle.

Things to note:

1. Removed `JavaScript` for positioning of arrow
2. Added this to .modal-arrow class:

   `top: 50vh;
   transform: translateY(-50%);`

If you don't know, `vh` stands for viewport height. A value of 50 means half of the available viewport height. I added the translateY(-50%) to more precisely align the arrow object in the vertical space. Translation is a cleaner, more modern way to vertically center and is a good replacement for using negative `margin-top`.

Chrome/Mac 49.0.2623.112

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same problem - the vertical positioning is not the issue, the horizontal positioning is.

The arrow still sits to the extreme left of the view port, rather than directly adjacent to the modal.

Comment: @MeltingDog Did you already view the static button from my fork of your fiddle? Which browser are you seeing this issue? Also, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide a screenshot of exactly what you want or try to describe what you're after in a different way?

Comment: Basically your .gif shows exactly what I am try to achieve - arrow stats static whilst modal scrolls.

But on your fork the arrow stays to the left of the screen whilst the modal stays centered, meaning that if I stretch the screen a gap appears between the arrow and the modal (sorry, the setup here wont let me take a screenshot).

I am using Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Haha thanks, this is sooo close. Now the problem is the arrow doesnt align with the triggering button (that what that JQuery did - it found the triggering buttons distance from the top of the screen and added top: Xpx to the arrow).

Comment: Well, to be fair, the modal doesn't really align with the triggering buttons, either. I got you most of the way. You should be able to figure the rest from here. It's just a matter of tweaking CSS for the modal positioning itself as well as the arrow. Make sure to check out the @media query I added for the `.modal-arrow `. You'll probably have to make a few changes to it.

Comment: It turns out that I could use the css in your media query to make it work! Farout, this was a touch one. Can you put your latest fiddle in the answer so I can accept?

Comment: The latest fiddle is in my answer. Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this...

```
.modal-arrow {left: 35px
```

check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umv4jhLg/6/

Comment: That would only work it there were set, static margins. If you stretch your browser window you will see they will come apart.

Answer (score -1):

First, have to separate them like how you did in your static example. But also you want to keep them together when window is resized horizontally, than with a basic approach take them into columns individually

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="modal-arrow" id="left">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10" id="right">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        ...
        </div>
</div>
```

while arrow is fixed, it is better to inherit it's width instead of try to fix it right and for the border intersection, arrow takes the priority.

```
#left {
   width: inherit;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 17px;
}
```

And remove the left part of margins

```
$('#right').find('*').css('margin-left', '0');
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/cmlonder/pen/YqjQGL) is the working fiddler.